# How to get out of this parse error in json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var bio = {
    "name": "Belphy Baby",
    "role": "student",
    "contacts": {
        "mobile": "9567166100",
        "email": "belphy16@gmail.com",
        "github": "belphy16",
        "location": "kottayam"
    },
    "welcome message": "and miles to go before i sleep",
    "skills": ["leadership", "enthusiastic", "learning"],
    "bioPic": "images/fry.jpg"
}

$("#main").append(bio);
```

Results in error:

> Parse error on line 1:
>   var bio = { "name":
>   ^
>   Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Comment: Please always post the code itself  instead of images of the code.

Comment: JSON doesn't have a `var` keyword, variables, or an assignment operator. Those indicate the snippet is JavaScript. And, a JSON parser doesn't understand JavaScript.

Comment: I have no idea why you're trying to append a json but surely there is no error in this https://jsfiddle.net/kqf6ywzz/ or https://jsfiddle.net/kqf6ywzz/1/ I guess if you want to display your json use html of jquery of innerHTML of javascript append is used to append HTML elements

Answer (score 1):

Input should be just a JSON at [JSONLint.com](http://JSONLint.com)

```
 {
    "name": "Belphy Baby",
    "role": "student",
    "contacts": {
        "mobile": "9567166100",
        "email": "belphy16@gmail.com",
        "github": "belphy16",
        "location": "kottayam"
    },
    "welcome message": "and miles to go before i sleep",
    "skills": ["leadership", "enthusiastic", "learning"],
    "bioPic": "images/fry.jpg"

 }
```

EDIT:

Answer is based on OP's [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41033327/1). Note the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7O1a.png) he provided.

The error he's getting is coming from the misuse of the site's JSON validation service. 
As the service's name suggests, it validates a JSON file's syntax.

Our OP's code contains hints of JavaScript. If inputted at JSONLint, it will give us his error; stating that the should-be JSON input has an error.